# Scrapy follow pagination in second level callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code and i need to follow all pagination links in my function parse_with_additional_info

```
start_urls = ['http://example.com']

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    aa = sel.xpath('//h3/a...../@href').extract()
    for a in aa:
        yield Request(url = a, callback=self.parse_additional_info)

def parse_additional_info(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    nextPageLinks=sel.xpath("//a[text([contains(.,'Next')]]/@href").extract()
```

Please note: I already tried scrapy rules and that did not work since its a chain of callbacks.

Comment: what are you getting in nextPageLinks according to your current code?

Comment: I found the answer by myself. I had to use response.urljoin with the next page link and callback the same function until no pages left.Here is the code it may help some one with  same scenario.                                     'def parse_additional_info(self, response):  ...... if nextPageLinks:
            url = response.urljoin(nextPageLinks[0])
            yield Request(url = url, callback=self.parse_additional_info)
       '

Comment: please do answer the question yourself. Its definitely better to have the answer in the answer section.

Comment: Yeah thanks @RoshanJossey.added the answer just.

Comment: Is it impossible to use method from the middle of the chain to follow links?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself. I had to use urljoin method of response object with nextPageLinks url and callback the same function until no pages left.
Here is the code it may help some one with same scenario.

```
def parse_additional_info(self, response):
 .
 .

if nextPageLinks: 
   url = response.urljoin(nextPageLinks[0]) 
   yield Request(url = url, callback=self.parse_additional_info)
```